# Should progress be retained if browser Back button is pressed during a progress tracker task?

Tags: back-button, multi-step

If I have 3 steps and I'm actually in the 2nd one, what should happen when I press on the back button?

Would a user expect to maintain the previous configuration of the 1st step, or should it reset and I have to set it up again?

[image: example of back button]

Answer (score 1):

A user would assume that this kind of navigation would move backward and forward in the steps.

In the step navigation, a button labelled *back* should not reset the progress. Especially when the user has done a lot of work filling out the forms, it would be really annoying.

Exiting the form and opening it again could reset the form. But again, if there are lots of filled fields, make sure to ask if it's okay that the progress will be lost.

Back button goes a step back, next button goes a step forward.